# Объединить 2 словаря и сохранить все значения для общих ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Нужно сделать из двух словарей один, при этом сохранив значения для одинаковых ключей.

При выполнении этого кода:

```
dict1 = {2: 'Samsung', 1: 'OnePlus', 4: 'Dell'}
dict2 = {3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG', 4: 'Apple'}

dict3 = mergeDict(dict1, dict2)
 
print(dict3)
```

получаю ошибку:

> NameError: name 'mergeDict' is not defined

Ожидаемый результат:

```
{3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG', 4: ['Dell', 'Apple'], 1: 'OnePlus', 2: 'Samsung'}
```

Порядок элементов не имеет значения.

Comment: по-моему сообщение об ошибке достаточно понятно говорит, что функция `mergeDict` не определена...

Comment: я это понимаю, но при обращении к гуглу, результатов нет. а в одном из примеров использовался этот метод. возможно этот способ был рабочим на более ранних версиях python, а сейчас нужно что-то подкрутить, чего я не знаю. поэтому и обратился сюда

Comment: можете привести в вопросе как должен выглядеть результат объединения?

Comment: {3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG', 4: ['Dell', 'Apple'], 1: 'OnePlus', 2: 'Samsung'}

порядок элетентов не имеет значения

Comment: Подкрутить не получится, не было такой функции. Или найти ее там, где взят пример, или написать самостоятельно. И переведи заголовок на русский язык.

Comment: [здесь](https://thispointer.com/how-to-merge-two-or-more-dictionaries-in-python/) есть определение искомой функции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        if dict1.get(k):
            dict1[k] = [dict1[k], v]
        else:
            dict1[k] = v        
    return dict1

dict1 = {2: 'Samsung', 1: 'OnePlus', 4: 'Dell'}
dict2 = {3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG', 4: 'Apple'}

dict3 = mergeDict(dict1, dict2)

print(dict3)

# {2: 'Samsung', 1: 'OnePlus', 4: ['Dell', 'Apple'], 3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeDicts(*dicts: [dict, ]) -> dict:
    dt = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            try:
                dt[k].add(v)
            except KeyError:
                dt[k] = v
            except AttributeError:
                dt[k] = {dt[k], v}
    return dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
    dict3 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
        dict3[k].append(v)
    return dict3
```

Comment: Вы хотели спросить, работает ли приведённая вами функция?