# Слияние повторяющихся значений в списке словарей python

Tags: python, dict

У меня есть список словарей в котором находятся эти данные:

```
dg = [{'patterns': 'знаю только понаслышке .','responses': 'а я слышал , и не раз .'},
{'patterns': 'знаю только понаслышке .', 'responses': 'зато я слышал .'},
{'patterns': 'знаю только понаслышке .', 'responses': 'оттуда видно всю долину .'},
{'patterns': 'знаю только понаслышке .', 'responses': 'я слышал , там многое изменилось .'}
{'patterns': 'ладно , повесь трубку .','responses': 'не могу .'},
{'patterns': 'ладно , повесь трубку .', 'responses': 'нет , звонить буду я .'},
{'patterns': 'ладно , повесь трубку .', 'responses': 'я звоню им .'},
{'patterns': 'ладно , повесь трубку .', 'responses': 'я не прекращу звонить .'}]
```

Что я только не делал, но все никак не удается пересобрать словарь так, чтобы повторяющиеся значения в 'patterns' были объединены, чтобы получился следующие вид:

```
dg = [{'patterns': 'знаю только понаслышке .', 'responses': ['а я слышал , и не раз .', 'зато я слышал .', 'оттуда видно всю долину .', ' я слышал , там многое изменилось .']},
      {'patterns': 'ладно , повесь трубку .', 'responses': ['не могу .', 'нет , звонить буду я .', 'я звоню им .', 'я не прекращу звонить .']}
```

Что только не пробовал, все никак не выходит это реализовать.

Comment: очень жаль. Пытайся пробовать дальше, но ни в коем случае не показывай никому своих попыток.

Comment: @Эникейщик что бы ты понимал, я везде искал ответ на этот вопрос, но нигде нет ответа

Comment: @Эникейщик тут не нужно **искать** ответ, тут нужно решить задачу, она весьма тривиальная

Comment: `dg` точно словарь, а не, например, список словарей?

Comment: @JonnyNamreh а) плохо искал. Даже на этом сайте периодически бывают похожие вопросы. б) Если не находится, то можно включить мозги и решить задачу самостоятельно, она не такая уж и сложная.

Comment: А можно уточнить, как у вас задан dg изначально? В вопросе написано нечто весьма странное. По крайней мере списка словарей там точно нет.

Comment: @passant dg это таблица csv которая преобразована при помощи tbl.to_dict('records')

Comment: @Jonny Namreh Ну я рад, что вы исправили первоначальное "безобразие".  Теперь хоть что-то стало понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def group(list_):
    values = set(map(lambda x: x["patterns"], list_))
    res = [{"patterns": value, "responses": []} for value in values]
    
    for dict_ in list_:
        for i in range(len(res)):
            if dict_["patterns"] == res[i]["patterns"]:
                res[i]["responses"].append(dict_["responses"])
                
    return res
```

Comment: это потрясающе, вы мне так сильно помогли, я с этой проблемой уже несколько дней разобраться не мог

Answer (score 1):

В словаре не может быть совпадающих ключей. Поэтому, то, что у Вас показано, это не словарь. Это даже синтаксически неверно. Это просто запись нескольких отдельных словарей в виде, который не является даже куском Python программы.

Похоже, Вас интересует слияние **нескольких** словарей, таким образом, что бы в поле значения присутсвовали **списки** значений. Эта задача обсуждалась много раз. например [так](https://coderoad.ru/18835392/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-Python) и [так](https://coderoad.ru/19115034/python-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

На мой взгляд, самое элегентное решение приведено [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048708/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9)

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        if dict1.get(k):
            dict1[k] = [dict1[k], v]
        else:
            dict1[k] = v        
    return dict1

dict1 = {2: 'Samsung', 1: 'OnePlus', 4: 'Dell'}
dict2 = {3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG', 4: 'Apple'}

dict3 = mergeDict(dict1, dict2)

print(dict3)

# {2: 'Samsung', 1: 'OnePlus', 4: ['Dell', 'Apple'], 3: 'ASUS', 5: 'LG'}
```

Comment: я не совсем корректно задал вопрос, я его уже изменил, ваш метод не совсем подходит.